# Rails nested forms multiple layers deep

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know the best way to label this but basically, I have 3 models,

Course: A subject, which has many Sessions
Session: Has many Slots that make up one session
Slot: Has a date and time which it happens on

The idea is, if you are interested in a Course, you register to take a Session. Each Session will have the same number of Slots, but these could be at different times of the month (e.g. you could take a 5 day session on the 30th July to 3rd Aug, or the same session a week later, 6th Aug to 10th Aug)

So I need to try and set up my nested for, so you can add or remove Sessions, each one should have the same number of nested Slots (based on a number in a drop down somewhere up the form).

Can anyone think of a nice way of doing this? or even a nasty way? I'm having trouble :)

## Update

I have it working with some JS and stuff, but now when it saves, it always errors saying Sessions slot session is not valid -- its not setting the slots session_id to its parent session and its not setting the sessions course_id to the course

I can't work out why. Anyone seen this before? The objects are in the has_many array...

## Update 2

{"title"=>"test123", "description"=>"test123", "sessions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"slots_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"when(3i)"=>"10", "when(2i)"=>"8", "when(1i)"=>"2012", "when(4i)"=>"10", "when(5i)"=>"00", "_destroy"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"when(3i)"=>"10", "when(2i)"=>"8", "when(1i)"=>"2012", "when(4i)"=>"10", "when(5i)"=>"00", "_destroy"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "3"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "4"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "5"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "6"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "7"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "8"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "9"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "10"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "11"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "12"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "13"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "14"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "15"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "16"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "17"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "18"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "19"=>{"when(3i)"=>"", "when(2i)"=>"", "when(1i)"=>"", "when(4i)"=>"", "when(5i)"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1"}}}}}

## Update 3

adding this code before saving has fixed it, although I don't know why I need it.

```
def apply_nested_models_hack
  ## HACK ##
  
  @course.sessions.each do |s|
    s.course = @course
    s.slots.each { |ss| ss.session = s }
  end
  
  ## /HACK ##
end
```

I'd like to know why the relationships aren't getting set, even though I've fixed my issue I've not answered the question.

## Update 4

It turns out this was not the nested forms but the fact I had:

```
validates :session, presence: true
```

on Slot - ActiveRecord doesn't set this side of the relationship until after saving, therefore it was considered invalid and wouldn't save. I'd consider this a bug in AR as it should show the relationships as they were in the database, even if they haven't been persisted yet.

Comment: Well the output doesn't look good at all. Can you copy/paste the code of the form please? Preferably in a gist or pastebin ... the post is getting long!

Comment: I've basically got it rendering 20 items, setting _destroy=1 for everything it isn't using and hiding them. This is working and that output is what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was not the nested forms but the fact I had:

```
validates :session, presence: true
```

on Slot - ActiveRecord doesn't set this side of the relationship until after saving, therefore it was considered invalid and wouldn't save. I'd consider this a bug in AR as it should show the relationships as they were in the database, even if they haven't been persisted yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using just Rails, nesting several level deep will be tricky. Possible for sure, but it can get messy.

I suggest you take a look at this gem : https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/

I didn't use it but it seems very promising

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've actually written something very similar. My main problem is either showing the correct number of Slots and having them populate server side correctly. The closest I've got is adding 20 slots by default when a Session is created, then hiding/showing the correct amount with javascript, then on the server side removing the extras - This works but the session_id is never set for the Slot, and errors every time.. Couldn't work this one out

Comment: I'd start by analyzing what you're sending to your controller from the form in the dev log file!

Comment: It appears to be sending the right stuff, {"sessions_attributes" => {"0" => {"slots_attributes" => {"0" => ...., "1" => ....}}, "1" => {"slots_attributes" => {"0" => ...., "1" => ....}}} looks correct!

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132 => Take a look at `attr_accessible` in this page too

Comment: Yes - I have the accepts_nested_attributes_for and attr_accessible, the nested model objects are getting set, but just seems to be the foreign IDs of the models aren't getting set

Comment: Ok then right before calling the `create` function in the controller, try logging `params.inspect` and copy/paste the whole output in the question

Comment: Many thanks for your help - I've added the detail you requested which is params[:course] (I didn't format as code as it put it all on 1 line that went off the screen!)